# Error while fetching XML Nodes using selectSingleNode in MSXML

Tags: xml, xpath, domdocument

Fetch XML Nodes using selectSingleNode in MSXML

I am trying to get the title field in below XML, but not able to

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rg:Group xmlns:rg="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS">
<r:license xmlns:r="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" Id="{b11f85f6-59c1-4c17-9c22-d951ac7257}"><r:title>XrML 2.1 License</r:title>
(some fields)
</r:license>
</rg:Group>
```

Below is my code in XML

```
var objXML = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");
objXML.async = false;
objXML.load("\\license.xml");
var ns="xmlns:rg='urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS' +"xmlns:r='urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS'"
objXML.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", ns);
objXML.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
WScript.Echo("ns:(after setProperty())\n  "+objXML.getProperty("SelectionNamespaces"));

var node = objXML.selectSingleNode("//Group/license/title");
WScript.Echo("root: \n"+node.text); //returns null
```

Comment: Here is the XML: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rg:Group xmlns:rg="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS"><r:license xmlns:r="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" Id="{b11f85f6-59c1-4c17-9c22-5cd951ac7257}"><r:title>XrML 2.1 License - </r:title></r:license></rg:Group>

Answer (score 0):

**The Xpath expression must be** (otherwise the registering of namespaces is meaningless):

```
//r:Group/r:license/r:title
```

**Also, you need to register just one namespace**, as the prefixes `"rg"` and `"r"` happen to be bound to the same namespace.

**The prefix you register doesn't need to be the same as any of the prefixes used in the XML document** -- it can be `"x"`, and the expression then will be:

```
//x:Group/x:license/x:title
```